# WAV encoding problem

Tags: fourier-transform, dsp-core, wave

When processing wav files, I encounter this problem: the what I extract PCM from a 8-bit encoded .wav file, I got a sequence of integers. However, when verifying my implementation with `wavread` in Matlab, the PCM code is represented with so-called `double-precision normalized samples`. My question is what's the difference between these two format. For example, the hex number is 0x80 0x81, the corresponding `double-precision normalized samples` are 0, 0.0078. IIRC, PCM code in .wav file records sound pressure value of audio. Is `double-precision normalized samples` sound pressure level? If so the value should be $10log(P_1/P_2)$ (based 10). But $10log(129/128)$is not 0.078 instead $10ln(129/128)$(based $e$) is. Anything wrong with my intuition?

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PCM values are **proportional** to the sound pressure. 8-bit PCM is stored with an offset of 128, so PCM coded values from 0 to 255 code for 'pressure values' from -128 to 127.
These values are often normalized to the range -1.0..+1.0.
The PCM values are linear representation of the sound pressure, and a log operation is only required if you want to express the sound pressure in decibels.
To get actual sound pressure levels in Pascal or dB(A) you would need a calibrated .wav signal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the 0.0078 comes from $(129-128)/128$?

Comment: Yes, the [0, 255] range is mapped to [-1, 1 - 1 / 256.0] using the transformation you gave.

Comment: @pichenettes Thanks. Thank you all. That's what I need!

Comment: One more point unclear: given PCM values are linear representation of sound pressure, then what is the factor? If @Hilmar said is right that `with an arbitary scale factor`, how could we reproduce the audio from PCM, i.e. how could we determine the precise value of the signal? Thanks.

Comment: You need to calibrate the microphone for that. A calibrator generates a signal with a precisely known sound pressure level, then from the recorded PCM levels you can calculate the scale factor.

Comment: "8-bit PCM is stored with an offset of 128" Isn't it better to just say that it's stored as signed bytes in 2's complement?

Comment: @endolith -1 in 2's-complement is 1111110 binary. In 8-bit PCM -1 is 01111111.

Comment: @Han: Oh, didn't know that.  ["There are some inconsistencies in the WAV format: for example, 8-bit data is unsigned while 16-bit data is signed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Description)  "8-bit samples are stored as unsigned bytes, ranging from 0 to 255. 16-bit samples are stored as 2's-complement signed integers, ranging from -32768 to 32767." https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/wavread.html

waveread() has an extra argument that will allow to read data in it's "native" format so you can avoid the output scaling and conversion to double precision. It has also optional output arguments that describe the exact format (sample rate, word width, etc.).

The data is supposed to be proportional to the linear sound pressure but with an arbitrary scale factor. 8 bit is rather poor resolution for audio, this may not be good enough to do any sound pressure level calculation